# Getting error while updateing the document using mongoDB and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting the following error while updating my document using MongoDB and Node.js.

Error:

```
TypeError: db.profile.updateOne is not a function
    at exports.updateProfile (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\route\route.js:101:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\e
xpress\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:1
31:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\
route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\e
xpress\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express\li
b\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:2
71:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express-sess
ion\index.js:433:7)
    at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:425:18)
```

I am using the `mongojs` driver to connect the mongoDB.I am explaining my code below.

```
exports.updateProfile=function(req,res){
    var colg_name=req.body.colg_name;
    var colg_shname=req.body.colg_shname;
    var address=req.body.address;
    var cont_no=req.body.cont_no;
    var email=req.body.email;
    var id=req.body.id;
    db.profile.updateOne({_id:db.ObjectId(id)},{$set:{colgname:colg_name,colgSname:colg_shname,address:address,contno:cont_no,email:email}},function(err,docs){
        if(!err){
            if(docs){
                res.send("Profile has updated suceessfully");
            }
        }
        if(err){
            res.send("Profile could not updated suceessfully");
        }
    });
}
```

I was following [this link](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/update/) to update the record.Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access to the db object and then collection objects for your profile collection.  One way is to make a connection in a file called db.js and then export the db object which can be "required" by other scripts or the other way is to make your updateProfile function accept the db or collection object as a a parameter in function.  The error is occurring because the objects doesn't have the properties you think it has.